# Show Button 5 seconds after program start

Tags: button, javafx

Does someone know how to show a button (Javafx) 5 seconds after the program start. It is a button that allows to go to the next page.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `PauseTransition` and set event handler on finished transition. Start your transition on primary stage on shown event handler.

```
Button delayedButton = new Button("Next");
delayedButton.setVisible(false);
primaryStage.setOnShown(ev -> {
    PauseTransition pt = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(5));
    pt.setOnFinished(e -> {
        delayedButton.setVisible(true);
    });
    pt.play();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! "Primary Stage cannot be resolved". What should I do?

Comment: I don't understand. Just copy/paste my code snippet into your `start(Stage primaryStage)`  method.

Comment: It is not in the primaryStage class. It is in a public class, that is controlled my the main (primaryStage) class.

Comment: Then pass `primaryStage` to that class - not prefered solution or add `Button` to scene graph and then get access to `primaryStage`. `delayedButton.getScene().getWindow().setOnShown(ev -> {});`

Comment: This solution was even with the idea that you have a basic understanding of JavaFX. If you want an answer that fits your code, you need to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).